# how to fix the switch button using bootstrap4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a switch button using bootstrap version 4.3. I have linked the CSS to the HTML file and all the css are working except for the switch button I'm trying to use.

I have seen a few designs implemented and used it on my template but they the classes are not working. I have checked and couldn't find the class in the bootstrap.min.css. I am not able to find out why the class is not present in the css I included. I have downloaded the javascript and CSS from the www.getbootstrap.com

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>IOT</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
          <label class="switch switch-pill switch-label switch-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked>
            <span class="switch-slider" data-checked="On" data-unchecked="Off"></span>
          </label>
          
        <!-- footer end here -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not need additional CSS or anything else. Switches were shipped in [Boostrap v.4.2.0](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26952). Are you sure you have the right bootstrap version (v.4.2.0 or above) ? You need the custom-switch class as well, see [#switches](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#switches)

Answer (score 1):

First You need to give CSS explicity to enable the toggle switch

```
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Example</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <style>
    .switch {
              position: relative;
              display: inline-block;
              width: 60px;
              height: 34px;
            }
    .switch input { 
                  opacity: 0;
                  width: 0;
                  height: 0;
                }
    .slider {
                  position: absolute;
                  cursor: pointer;
                  top: 0;
                  left: 0;
                  right: 0;
                  bottom: 0;
                  background-color: #ccc;
                  -webkit-transition: .4s;
                  transition: .4s;
                }

    .slider:before {
                  position: absolute;
                  content: "";
                  height: 26px;
                  width: 26px;
                  left: 4px;
                  bottom: 4px;
                  background-color: white;
                  -webkit-transition: .4s;
                  transition: .4s;
                }

                input:checked + .slider {
                  background-color: #2196F3;
                }

                input:focus + .slider {
                  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
                }

                input:checked + .slider:before {
                  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
                  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
                  transform: translateX(26px);
                }

                /* Rounded sliders */
        .slider.round {
                  border-radius: 34px;
                }

        .slider.round:before {
                  border-radius: 50%;
                }
</style>
  </head>

  <body>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try this once

Answer (score 0):

You have not included complete JS and CSS libraries. I have tried to include below within `<head>` tag and switch button worked out.

You are not only just using Bootstrap but also classes for Core-UI that must be included, I think.

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css">


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui/dist/js/coreui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He included it, he's hosting it himself or so it seems, I think it has to do with his version of Bootstrap.

Comment: He is using CSS of core-ui. So, I think it needs to be fixed

Comment: It has nothing to do with it. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjake/ryqeapwx/2/), I included Core-UI and Bootstrap 4.3.1, it works straight out of the box.

Comment: Yes. this is what I'm talking about. I already did the same as well before :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this!

 **HTML**

 <form>
   <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="custom-control-input" id="switch1">
         <label class="custom-control-label" for="switch1"></label>
      </div>
 </form> 

**CSS**


 .custom-control-label {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.custom-control-input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
}
.custom-switch {
    padding-left: 2.25rem;
}
.custom-control {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
}
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #0b55c1;
    background-color: #0b55c1;
}
.custom-switch .custom-control-label::before {
    left: -2.25rem;
    width: 1.75rem;
    pointer-events: all;
    border-radius: .5rem;
}
.custom-control-label::before, .custom-file-label, .custom-select {
    transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
.custom-control-label::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: .25rem;
    left: -1.5rem;
    display: block;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    border: #adb5bd solid 1px;
}
.custom-switch .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(.75rem);
    transform: translateX(.75rem);
}
.custom-switch .custom-control-label::after {
    top: calc(.25rem + 2px);
    left: calc(-2.25rem + 2px);
    width: calc(1rem - 4px);
    height: calc(1rem - 4px);
    background-color: #adb5bd;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .15s ease-in-out;
}
.custom-control-label::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: .25rem;
    left: -1.5rem;
    display: block;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    content: "";
    background: no-repeat 50%/50% 50%;
}
```